# How to access the secondary back camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

My MI8 phone set has two back cameras, but Camera.open() can only access 0 and 1, for the front and back camera. How could I access the secondary back camera?

Answer (score 0):

Most vendors provide dual cameras with a specific function, like getting a better picture quality or a selfie mode.
The techniques vary from vendor to vendor, so you won't be finding documentation all the time.

So there might be chance that even if you use your camera via the official app, it won't always pass both lenses. So if there is no documentation you don't have to worry about using the second lens, because it will be hard to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will ROOT help?

Comment: I don't really know if having a rooted device will help with that, as there is no specific documentation for Xiaomi devices

Comment: With root access, you can try to listen to V4L streams `/dev/videoX`. Without the specific device at hand, it's hard to tell what you can achieve this way.